# Wait async operation to complete in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm processing a lot of data in one ViewController using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/) like this :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, APIENDPOINT)
        .responseJSON { (_, _, jsondata, _) in
            // whole lotta json parsing and creating custom objects from json
    }
```

Essentialy, data is grabbed in one view controller which acts as loading screen that notifies user that something is going on in the background. Then when async request complete and all data is populated, data is shown in another view controller.

What is the best way to achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Do it such that the viewcontroller which sends the request waits until the data has been loaded and parsed into some useful model components. Then, initialize another viewcontroller, pass the  parsed data from remote and then show/push it.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, APIENDPOINT)
  .responseJSON { (_, _, jsondata, _) in
    // whole lotta json parsing and creating custom objects from json
  let anotherViewController = AnotherViewController()
  anotherViewController.dataFromRemote = parsedRemoteData
  self.showViewController(anotherViewController, animated:true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use a manual segue. Something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, APIENDPOINT)
    .responseJSON { (_, _, jsondata, _) in
        // whole lotta json parsing and creating custom objects from json
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("realViewController", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
  if segue.identifier == "realViewController" {
    let vc:MyViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as MyViewController
    vc.setupWithData(self.myParsedData)
  }
}
```